# Outlook advanced plain text output formatting

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, formatting, microsoft-outlook-2003

I have to use Mixrosoft Outlook 2003 at work but I need the following formatting when I hit the 'Reply' button.

Currently I get this format on replying to a message:

```
Reply email text starts here...

-----Original Message-----
> From: <me@mail.com>
> Sent: 27 August 2009 14:38
> To: <sender@mail.com>
> Subject: Re: What do you think?
> 
> Here's a test message, hit reply and what format do you get?
```

But the format I would like (and need) is:

```
> On Thu, Aug 27, 2009 at 2:48 PM, <sender@mail.com> wrote:
> 
> Here's a test message, hit reply and what format do you get?
```

Anyone also had this problem? Any thoughts on a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to write an outlook plugin to extract and replace that block of code, I don't think its worth it to be honest, explain to Management / Business that that is just the default behaviour of Outlook 2003, and it would be pretty extreme to change it.

I know this is not a technical answer, but try to think out of the technical box for a sec, do you really think its worth the hassle of building, debugging, testing, installing and supporting a plugin, just to get prettier reply to fields?